# Display each DISTINCT Field Value only once using loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
SELECT listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt, mBCFName, mBCLName, moAmt, moDtOff
FROM User U, Listing L, Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO
WHERE U.uID = L.uID
and L.listID = MO.listID
and M.mID = MO.mId
ORDER BY listDt DESC;
```

**This foreach() loop**

```
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row) 
    { 
    echo "<div class='listing'>";
        print '<br>Title: ' . $row['listTitle'] . '<br>Comment: ' . $row['listCmt'] . 
        '<br>Date: ' . $row['listDt'] . '<br>Offer By: ' . $row['mBCFName']. ' ' .$row['mBCLName']. '<br> for: ' . $row['moAmt'];
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

**produces:**

[image]

Basically what I want is:

```
Title: Apple iPhone 4S (listTitle)
Days: <some day amount <listLength>
Comment: some comment <listCmt>

    Offer By: some user <mBCFName mBCLName>
    Offer:  19.99 <moAmt>
    Date: 10/03/2011 < moDtOff>

    Offer By: some user <mBCFName mBCLName>
    Offer:  19.99 <moAmt>
    Date: 10/03/2011 < moDtOff>

    Offer By: some user <mBCFName mBCLName>
    Offer:  19.99 <moAmt>
    Date: 10/03/2011 < moDtOff>

    Offer By: some user <mBCFName mBCLName>
    Offer:  19.99 <moAmt>
    Date: 10/03/2011 < moDtOff>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to print `listTitle` as a *group heading* above the relevant comments.

One way to do it would be to keep track of `listTitle` of the previous row, and then only print it if there's a difference with the current row. Of course, you'd have to make sure your result set is ordered by `listTitle`.

Another way would be to have one query that gets all data for that group heading, then another query that gets the contents of the group.

It is also probably possible to do it in the query, but that will be tricky since you want the first record with that `listTitle` to have a value for `listTitle` and the others to have `null` - until the next `listTitle` that's different.

Comment: @user975947: I don't have time at the moment to try to write an actual working code solution. Is there some part of any of these descriptions that isn't clear?

Comment: It makes sense, but how is this little script going to iterate through all the combinations that match. For instance, `Title: Apple iPhone 4S` might ONLY have certain comments that pertain to that title. I thought of doing this with the two scripts.. one for the title, another for the rest of it. But, I dont know how they would match the `listTitle` with the other fields if its two seperate queries. Make sense?

Comment: Can you write out some rough code? I would really really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that every field is the same (listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt, mBCFName, mBCLName, moAmt, moDtOff) the change is easiest in the SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt, mBCFName, mBCLName, moAmt, moDtOff
```

If it's not the same, then how would the code be able to decide which *New Balance 574 Men's Shoes* to display?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that easy - the question is what to show for the other field (for example the "mBCFName" field - "Amanda" OR "John")?

use the "Group by" SQL statement and then define the rules (max,min,avg, GROUP_CONCAT ...) to select the other rows - Example:

```
SELECT listTitle, min(listLength), min(listCmt), min(listDt), GROUP_CONCAT(mBCFName), min(mBCLName), min(moAmt), min(moDtOff)
FROM User U, Listing L, Merchant M, MerchantOffer MO
WHERE U.uID = L.uID
  and L.listID = MO.listID
  and M.mID = MO.mId
GROUP BY listTitle
ORDER BY listDt DESC;
```